# How to get the exact total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Query

`Select 9/5` 'Showing output as `1`

I want to get the exact ouput for 9/5

Expected Ouput

```
1.8 instead of 1
```

How to make a query

Comment: use (float) to cast! it works in c++ :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is it is doing integer math. You can explicitly treat them as decimal numbers by adding `.0`:

```
SELECT 9.0 / 5.0
```

You can also use CONVERT or CAST to be even more explicit:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,4), 9) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,4), 5)
```

Note: If either of the operands are decimal numbers, the result will be a decimal number, so you technically only have to convert one of them. So any of these will also work:

```
SELECT 9 / 5.0
SELECT 9.0 / 5
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,4), 9) / 5
SELECT 9 / CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,4), 5)
```

The reason it works this was is because the ANSI/ISO-SQL standard actually says that the results of mathematical operations must be the same data type as one of the operands. So if both of the operands are integers, the result according to the ANSI/ISO-SQL standard must also be an integer.

MySQL violates the standard here (presumably in the interest of practicality), but MS SQL complies with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to sql-server, and mysql seems to give the correct answer. However, I'd try forcing one or both of the arguments to be floats (i.e SELECT 9.0 /5.0)